# Can't use sphinx's matplotlib extension with Qt on OS X

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, python-sphinx, anaconda

Using the Anaconda python distribution on OS X, you can't use the `anaconda/bin/python` binary when using a Qt backend for matplotlib (via my matplotlibrc file). On import it causes:

> Qt internal error: qt_menu.nib could not be loaded. The .nib file should be placed in
>   QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/  or in the resources
>   directory of your application bundle.

I get around this by prepending my PATH with `anaconda/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python`; however, sphinx-build explicitly uses `anaconda/bin/python`. Is there a way to tell the matplotlib sphinx extension to use a specific backend? I've tried modifying `plot_pre_code` in my `config.py`, but it doesn't work, so I assume matplotlib has already been imported by the time that code is run.

Comment: Setting some other backend in the matplotlibrc file doesn't work?

Comment: No, that didn't work, but it should have. Evidently I misunderstood the problem. The real problem was that autodoc was trying to document a module that was importing Mayavi with the Qt backend. Thanks for nudging me in the right direction!

Comment: Please write that up as an answer for your own question

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging, the answer to my question appears to be that sphinx is using a non-qt matplotlib backend even when I specify `Qt4Agg` in my `matplotlibrc`. The problem was that autodoc was commenting a module that imported Mayavi. In case any one else comes up against this, my fix was to put

```
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'null'
```

into sphinx's `conf.py` for my project.